# What could be causing the "OutputPath property is not set for project ProjectName.csproj" error in my MonoDevelop project

Tags: android, windows, xamarin.android, xamarin

On Windows 7 (64 bit) with the Android SDK working perfectly with Eclipse - my first android application, using the first "Hello World" sample (found here - http://docs.xamarin.com/android/getting_started/hello_world - from Xamarin)
fails with the error "the OutputPath property who is not set for project NameProject.csproj".

I have tried re-runing the installation program from Xamarin and this error still occurs.

Could someone please suggest what may be causing this problem?
Thanks a lot.

the exact error:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(9,9): 
Error: The OutputPath property is not set for project 'helloWorld3.csproj'.  
Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of 
Configuration and Platform for this project.  
Configuration='Debug'  
Platform='BPC'.  
This error may also appear if some other project is trying to follow a 
project-to-project reference to this project, this project has been 
unloaded or is not included in the solution, and the referencing project 
does not build using the same or an equivalent Configuration or Platform.
(helloWorld3)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think we've seen this before.  Your system manufacturer installed an environment variable called Platform onto your system.  This breaks all msbuild based stuff, since msbuild automatically imports that as $(Platform), conflicting with the real $(Platform) that msbuild uses to compile.

Try removing the environment variable and try again.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it Thursday on my Windows computer.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Hopefully helped Adrien G too. Perhaps accept this answer if it did @Adrien G